# Multiple calls from via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy agent

Tags: email, gmail, image-load

I am seeing increased number of calls from via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy agent for some of the URL fetches. 
Details: I have put in an image in the email html body. When I open the email, I expect a call to be made to my server to fetch this image. However, since Gmail uses its proxy server, I see multiple calls made at regular intervals (about ~500 calls per image. In one instance I have logs for 5000 calls for one image as well).

Any idea why the same image is fetched so many times?

Comment: I am seeing multiple calls from user agent "YahooMailProxy; https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-mail-proxy-SLN28749.html
" as well. This is yahoo's image proxy server.

Comment: looks like gmail [Apache logs flooded with connections - “(via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)”](https://serverfault.com/questions/581857/apache-logs-flooded-with-connections-via-ggpht-com-googleimageproxy)

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but because this is served by Google search: GoogleImagProxy anonymizes Gmail openings. So, if you use a newletter or auto-responder and somebody opens an email containing an image, usear-agent shows as GoogleImageProxy.